# Random request timeout

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, afnetworking, testflight

I'm writing an iOS application that uses AFNetworking and Google App Engine as a backend service. The problem I'm having is that on some really rare occasions my requests to the server will timeout. I have no idea on how to reproduce it. I have no idea if the problem is on the client or the server side.

If I kill the app or make a new request from another instance of the app, it works fine. I think the default time out is set to something like two minutes, so it has nothing to do with poor reception or that the timeout isn't long enough. A normal request completes in under a second.

So what I'm asking is, what is the best way to debug this?

**Edit: So I finally found [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/307) link. Seems to be a problem with Test Flight (which I'm using as well)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for debugging related to the internet issues, you can use some web debugging tools. There is a tool named, Charles proxy, that is easy to use and various features. You can control your internet bandwidth/speed etc to produce different scenarios to get a better debugging. here is the link: http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Thank you. I ran charlesproxy combined with notifications from AFNetworking and found that AFNetworking says that it starts an operation but nothing is logged in charlesproxy. So I'm now pretty sure that it's something with AFNetworking.